# OData DataServiceQuery deserialize only first element of collection

Tags: asp.net, collections, odata, expand, dataservice

On my ASP.NET MVC5 application, I have a service reference for an OData api.
I'm making a call for this API, expanding a child propertie, as follows:

```
DataServiceQuery<CenarioDeInvestimentoCenario> queryCenario;
queryCenario = context.CenarioDeInvestimentoCenario
    .Expand("CenarioDeInvestimentoCenarioItem")
    .Where(a => a.IdAerodromo.Equals(55)) as DataServiceQuery<CenarioDeInvestimentoCenario>;
QueryOperationResponse<CenarioDeInvestimentoCenario> response = queryCenario
    .IncludeTotalCount()
    .Execute() as QueryOperationResponse<CenarioDeInvestimentoCenario>;
```

This generates the following query string:

```
LocalHost/MyApi/CenarioDeInvestimentoCenario()?$filter=IdAerodromo eq 55&$expand=CenarioDeInvestimentoCenarioItem
```

Using this query string from any browser, I can get the correct result set of data as follows on the image bellow. Notice CenarioDeInvestimentoCenarioItem as a collection:

[image: Note that CenarioDeInvestimentoCenarioItem is a collection of several entities]

However, inside my ASP.NET application, on the QueryOperationResponse response object, I get just the first CenarioDeInvestimentoCenarioItem collection element, as shown on the pic below:

[image: Where is the rest of my collection???]

I have no idea why this is happening. I'm pretty new working with Odata and service reference, so I have no idea what is happening. Can someone help-me please?

Tx!

Comment: How does your model relationship look like? I had the same problem once and found out that I forgot the `virtual` keyword...

Comment: Thanx, Jan. Wasn't exactly that, but something similar:
The entity has a composite key and I forgot to tell the ODataConventionModelBuilder about that.
Changing `builder.EntitySet<CenarioDeInvestimentoCenarioItem>("CenarioDeInvestimentoCenarioItem").EntityType.HasKey(e => e.IdAerodromo);` to 
`builder.EntitySet<CenarioDeInvestimentoCenarioItem>("CenarioDeInvestimentoCenarioItem").EntityType.HasKey(e => new { e.IdAerodromo, e.IdCenario, e.IdItemDeInvestimento });` did the trick